# Trying to use Collections.sort (ArrayList<String>) and Collections.sort(ArrayList<String>, Comparator) with no luck

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I create a simple string arraylist as such:

```
ArrayList<String> filmDirectory = new ArrayList<String>();
filmDirectory.add("Gone with the Wind");
filmDirectory.add("The Sound of Music");
filmDirectory.add("The Titanic");
Collections.sort(filmDirectory);
```

The compiler prompts me to case the filmDirectory to a list, which I do, though I do not understand why I should do it, since and ArrayList is an extension of a List.

Still, when the code reaches to:

```
Collections.sort((List)filmDirectory);
```

I have a compiler error of:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to acmx.export.java.util.List

Implementing Comparator and defining compare method for the current class and using Collections.sort(filmDirectory, this) does not help either.

Comment: Make sure, your collection imports are from `java.util.*`. (at least the `List`
 obviously isn't).

Comment: You have imported the wrong List class. I'm guessing you have an incorrect java class path.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem. Imported the entire java.util.*, instead of part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've imported a wrong package for `Collections`: you are using `acmx.export.java.util` instead of `java.util.*`

Answer (score 1):

You should import the *List* and *ArrayList* classes of the *java.util* package. Delete the import concerning the *acmx.export.java.util* package and add these two lines of import :

```
import java.util.List
import java.util.ArrayList
```

It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `import java.util.*;` to avoid this errror.